# Is it possible to implement Objective-C protocol via Swift extension?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Wanted to implement conformance to this protocol using `extension` keyword to be more protocol oriented

Example:
Objective C:

```
@protocol ObjectiveCProtocol
-(void) protocolMethod;
@end
```

Swift:

```
class SwiftClass: ObjectiveCProtocol {}

extension ObjectiveCProtocol {
    func protocolMethod() {

    }
}
```

> Type 'SwiftClass' does not conform to protocol 'ObjectiveCProtocol'
>
> Protocol requires function 'protocolMethod()' with type '() -> Void'
>
> Candidate is not '@objc', but protocol requires it

Possible fix is to just add the implementation in the class itself, which is what im avoiding

Swift:

```
class SwiftClass: ObjectiveCProtocol {
    func protocolMethod() {

    }
}
```

Comment: You are using a feature that is available for Swift protocols but it is not available for Obj-C protocols (it is not supported in Obj-C). There is no way to fix that without adding that feature to Obj-C language and nobody will do that...

Comment: What you are trying to do is providing a default protocol implemantation. That's not possible for Objc protocols in Swift. What you can do, however, is to implement the protocol requirements for a specific class in an extension, like `extension SwiftClass: ObjectiveCProtocol`. However, those are two different things.

Comment: It seems this case is completely missing from the Swift documentation. I could not find it neither in the Guide or Obj-C interoperability section.